# Is it possible to see or add to a YouTube Analytics Video Group via the API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Groups are a new feature in YouTube Analytics that allow individual channels and MCNs to group both videos (primarily for individuals) or channels (only for MCNs) and view combined Analytics for all entities in the given group.

For authenticated users, is it possible to, via the YouTube Data API, to see existing groups, create new groups, add videos to groups, and to request summed/combined YouTube Analytics statistics for a group?

I can not find any documentation or questions on stack overflow about this, likely given how new the groups feature is.

More information on groups: https://support.google.com/youtube/topic/3529192

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, have you had any updates on this? I have a similar query and would be interested to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube Analytics API has been updated two days ago. It now supports the functionality you are looking for. Have a look at the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reference/groups